# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'history'

Tags: python, yfinance

Im trying to get the historical data of Tesla stock, but it doesnt recognize history() as a method.
Also im using yfinance==0.1.67

i tried to run this command:

```py
tesla = yf.download('TSLA')
tesla.history(period = "max")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one's easy. You probably want close prices, which you already have after the call to download.

```
import yfinance as yf
tesla = yf.download('TSLA')
close_prices = tesla.Close
print(close_prices)
```

```
Date
2010-06-29      1.592667
2010-06-30      1.588667
2010-07-01      1.464000
2010-07-02      1.280000
2010-07-06      1.074000
                 ...    
2023-05-26    193.169998
2023-05-30    201.160004
2023-05-31    203.929993
2023-06-01    207.520004
2023-06-02    213.970001
Name: Close, Length: 3255, dtype: float64
```